# RabbitMQ acknowledge messages later

Tags: .net, indexing, queue, rabbitmq

In order to avoid data loss in the event that the queue reader process crashes we need to get messages from RabbitMQ as unacknowledged. For every 1000 messages, we commit the message data to disk and then those messages can be marked as acknowledged and consumed. Is there a way to get them as unacknowledged and then target those specifically that we've just got? Could we, for instance, add them to a list and then iterate through that list to find the messages? 
This is in RabbitMQ .net FYI.

Comment: I wrote a blog post on this subject: http://pmichaels.net/2016/10/28/acknowledging-a-messing-using-rabbitmq/

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can consume messages from RabbitMQ and explicitely acknowledge the one you successfully handled. You can find a complete example in [the second tutorial on RabbitMQ website](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-dotnet.html). But here are the relevant parts of this tutorial:

1. When you setup your consumer, set `noAck` ("no manual ack") to false, so the .NET client library will not automatically ack messages:

   ```cs
   channel.BasicConsume(queue: "task_queue", noAck: false, consumer: consumer);
   ```
2. In your consumer callback, you explicitely ack a message:

   ```
   channel.BasicAck(deliveryTag: ea.DeliveryTag, multiple: false);
   ```

You can ack either one message (`multiple` is false), or all messages up-to and including this one (`multiple` is true).

You can also ["unacknowledge" messages](http://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/v3.6.1/rabbitmq-dotnet-client-3.6.1-client-htmldoc/html/type-RabbitMQ.Client.IModel.html#method-M:RabbitMQ.Client.IModel.BasicNack%28System.UInt64,System.Boolean,System.Boolean%29), so RabbitMQ can requeue it and send it to another worker for example. Like acknowledgement, you can tell if you want to unacknowledge one or all messages. Furthermore, you can set the `requeue` flag to true or false, to indicate if the message should be requeued or dropped.

Comment: Is there a way to update multiple messages that are not necessarily in order. May be by supplying a list of delivery tags to acknowledge? For example, there are three message 1, 2, 3, 4, I process 1 and 3 and acknowledge those at once and do some different processing on 2 and 4 and ack them afterwards

Comment: No, it's not possible with the AMQP `basic.ack` method: it takes a single message number and the `multiple` flag, with `true` meaning this message number and all previous ones should be acknowledged.